# how to Store the Calender Remainder on Day with time in android

Tags: android

i Create a Calender and also A click event On day With Open A List with time.How to add the calendar events with time on particular day with sq lite Database In android Here Is the Code For Create Calender On Grid View and Click Day Code With Static add the Events On.

MyCalenderActivity

```
public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity"; 

    private TextView currentMonth;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int month, year;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

    /*  selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
                .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");*/

        prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param month
     * @param year
     */
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == prevMonth) {
            if (month <= 1) {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            } else {
                month--;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
        }
        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 11) {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            } else {
                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Inner Class
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
        private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy");


        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         * 
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
            int prevMonth = 0;
            int prevYear = 0;
            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 0;
                prevYear = yy;
                nextYear = yy + 1;
                Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                prevMonth = 11;
                prevYear = yy - 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                nextMonth = 1;
                Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            } else {
                prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;
                prevYear = yy;
                daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                        + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                        + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
            }

            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                if (mm == 2)
                    ++daysInMonth;
                else if (mm == 3)
                    ++daysInPrevMonth;

            // Trailing Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
                Log.d(tag,
                        "PREV MONTH:= "
                                + prevMonth
                                + " => "
                                + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                                + " "
                                + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                        - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                        + i));
                list.add(String
                        .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                + i)
                        + "-GREY"
                        + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                        + "-"
                        + prevYear);
            }

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            }

            // Leading Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         * 
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
            }

            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

            // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];
            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.lightgray02));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
            }
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent ints=new Intent(MyCalendarActivity.this,DayViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(ints);
            //String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
            //selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
            //Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
        /*  try {
                Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
        }

        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }
    }

}
```

MyDayViewActivity

```
public class DayViewActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static int HOURS_PER_DAY = 24; 

Context mContext = this;
ImageView prev,next;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 



    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 12, 12));
    getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(){

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return HOURS_PER_DAY;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }


     @Override
        public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View listItem = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, getListView(),false);
            TextView hourTV = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.hourTV);
            TextView amTV = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.amTV);
            hourTV.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            amTV.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            final LinearLayout eventsLL = (LinearLayout) listItem.findViewById(R.id.eventsLL);
            hourTV.setText(String.valueOf((position+9)%24));
            //I set am/pm for each entry ... you could specify which entries
            if(((position>=0)&&(position<=2))||((position>=15)&&(position<=23)))
                amTV.setText("am");
            else
                amTV.setText("pm");
            eventsLL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); 

                    alert.setTitle("New Event"); 
                    alert.setMessage("Event:"); 

                    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                    final EditText input = new EditText(mContext); 
                    alert.setView(input); 

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
                            TextView A = new TextView(mContext);
                            A.setText(input.getText());
                            A.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            eventsLL.addView(A);
                        } 
                    }); 

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        } 
                    }); 
                    alert.show();
                }

            });
            return listItem;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
}
```

The Layout

My_calender_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:height="60sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Sun" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="mon" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="tue" />
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="wed" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="thu" />
             <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Fri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Fri" />
                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="sat" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="251dp"
        android:numColumns="7"
       android:layout_gravity="center" 
       >

    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenGridcell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
        style="@style/calendar_event_style"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For Day View

List_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingTop="5dip"
  android:paddingBottom="5dip"
  android:background="#CCC">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/hourTV" 
            android:text="" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/amTV" 
            android:text="" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LLdesign" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/eventsLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/eventbg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!--    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:height="60sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"    
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could try this.
SQLiteDatabase.execSQL so you can enter a raw SQL query.

```
mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE+" VALUES (null, datetime()) ");
```

Or the java date time capabilities :

```
// set the format to sql date time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("date_created", dateFormat.format(date));
long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```